# How do I display the values of a 2d array in angular 2+ in the template file for a yearly calendar?

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular8, stackblitz

I'm trying to build a yearly calendar.  Now I could have 12 month parents and all the children and that would do the trick, but I would rather cut down on html.  I have a variable called yearlyCalendarArr which is the 2d array of months with the correct days in them along with spaces (it's consoled logged in the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yearly-calendar?file=src/app/app.component.ts)).

HTML

```
<div id="yearly-calendar">
  <div class="month-holder" *ngFor="let days of yearlyCalendarArr; let i = index">
    <div class="month">
      <div class="month-header">
        <h5 class="month-name">{{months[i]}}</h5>    
      </div>

      <div class="month-body">
        <div class="week-divider">
          <div class="weekday" *ngFor="let w of weekdays">{{w[0]}}</div>
        </div>

        <div class="week-divider">
          <div class="calendar-box"></div>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In case anyone asks, yes I know, I have to handle leap years, and style better, I didn't include that in the OP so as to cut down on non essential code for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through day in `days` array something like

```
 <div class="month-divider">
     <div class="item" *ngFor="let d of days;let di=index">
       <div>{{d}}</div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

css

```
.month-divider {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.item {
   display: contents;
}
.item>div{

 width: 1.2em;
 flex:1;
  background: gold;
  text-align: left;
}

.item:nth-child(7n)::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
}
```

You may need some css fixes on big screen

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yearly-calendar-2d9ugq)

Comment: Thanks, yeah I just threw some styles for this question.